# Adding white space in PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I have PDF where some of the text are very closed to the left and right border and I would like to add more white space at the border, top bottom left and right, for each pages in the PDF using iTextSharp.

Is this possible using iTextSharp or there is a better way?

Comment: Are you editing an existing PDF file, or creating a new PDF file?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the answer. The code below adjusts the size of the pages:

```
var inputPdf = new PdfReader(inputFile);   // Get input document

int pageCount = inputPdf.NumberOfPages;

if (end < start || end > pageCount)
    end = pageCount;

var inputDoc = new Document(inputPdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)); 

using (var fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
{
    var outputWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(inputDoc, fs);
    inputDoc.Open();

    PdfContentByte cb1 = outputWriter.DirectContent;

    // Copy pages from input to output document
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        var existingRec = inputPdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i);
        var newRec = new Rectangle(0.0f, 0.0f, existingRec.Width + 50, existingRec.Height + 25, 0);

        inputDoc.SetPageSize(newRec);
        inputDoc.NewPage();

        PdfImportedPage page = outputWriter.GetImportedPage(inputPdf, i);
        int rotation = inputPdf.GetPageRotation(i);

        if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
             cb1.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, inputPdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
        else cb1.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 25, 13); 
    }

    inputDoc.Close();
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: what is end and start?

Comment: @CountLessQ public static void AddWhiteSpace(string inputFile, string outputFile, int start, int end) where start and end are the number of pages you wanna add white space, e.g. page 1 to page 3.